# Does Peewee support Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, peewee

Simple question guys, I am pretty new to Elasticsearch and just got to know about the Peewee package, I am interested to know if Peewee supports elasticsearch as the product that I am working on requires support for a wide variety of data sources.

Any help or pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), no.

Which makes sense, as ElasticSearch way of storing data is radically different than regular DBMS.

It's not relational as MySQL or PostGreSQL (supported by peewee), there are no transactions, no authentication (i.e. no built-in security).

As an aside, ORM means object-**relational** mapping, which doesn't make sense as far as ElasticSearch is concerned.

Comment: ,yeah even i was almost sure when i read this doc before posting the question but then i saw this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621726/getting-peewee-to-work-on-elastic-beanstalk
which kinda confused me :/

Comment: But according to [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html), Elastic beanstalk doesn't imply using ElasticSearch. The question you're mentioning mostly talks about MySQL.

Comment: Agree! Any other cool package you might know to implement graphs and charts where am using django rest to create api's and have to have a support of a variety of data sources ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't be of any help here, I don't know django/python ecosystem enough.